# Volatility Index for Industries

Tags: options, option-pricing, volatility, returns, vix

The VIX index is based on the S&P, I am wondering the feasibility of creating a VIX index for each of the S&P 500 Industries?

Would this even be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VIX Index is computed from option prices on S&P Index.
A VIX-like Index for other industries would first require to have a liquid option market.

Answer (score 1):

In theory that would be possible. However, liquidity in industries could in some instances be substantially less than liquidity in the SPX thus making the hedging of volatility derivatives such as vol futures more difficult. Also, there may not be sufficient interest from investors to make the launching of industry/sector specific vol indices feasible.

Comment: Depends which industry and what you mean with "market". The industry consisting of manufacturers of spectacles will not predict the SPX index volatility :) But more importantly, I do not believe that an index like the VIX is a forward looking indicator anyway. It is, and implied volatility in general, in fact lagging realized volatility.